# How to cut plane/ocean modifier?

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation, clipping

I am looking to clip the plane created by the ocean modifier - as a boolean modifier would do. This method worked well with a terrain with a simplier shape and only one dam.

The end result sould be that the water stops behind the 2 dams and doesn't go past the terrain.

What I tried:

- using the boolean modifier with each object one after the other terrain, dam1, dam2: this makes my ocean disappear
- useing the boolean modifier's collection operand type: this doesn't do anything (probably because the cube used as a start for the ocean modifier is small?)

[image]
The blue parts is what I want to cut out.

[image]
Just another view.

Comment: You will need an object that is continuous -- that includes both of the dam meshes AND connected by the terrain between them.    Perhaps make a duplicate of the dams, JOIN them.  In EDIT mode, select (rectangular subsets) of the closet unconnected vertices (top and bottom) and use Vertex >> New Edge/Face from Vertex 'f'.   You can use the result as your boolean object on the water surface.  Downside: if you want to change some aspect of one of the dams, you'd have to start over recreating the boolean object.

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem as I won't need to change the meshes anymore. Unfortunately I am stuck at "select (rectangular subsets) of the closet unconnected vertices (top and bottom)". How do I know what are the closest unconnected vertices (top and bottom) ? Wouldn't a simple ctrl - J be the same ?

Comment: I ended up deleting the vertices manually in EDIT mode. Not the best workflow but it did the job.